# How do I delete all DNS configuration and records?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I was wondering how I would be able to delete my entire DNS server configuration, including all DNS records on Windows Server 2012 r2. Is there a built in command or an available script to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question says "2012" but your tag says "2012 R2". Which one is it?

Comment: 2012 r2. I will update my question for future references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an up-to-date Powershell (and if you're on a remote computer, RSAT), and you want to ditch *EVERY* DNS record from a zone, and you feel like shooting yourself in the foot:

```
Import-Module DnsServer
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName dc01 -ZoneName ad.example.com | Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord
```

That will delete every record from the `ad.example.com` zone from the DNS server `dc01` (which will then replicate to other DNS servers in the domain if you have AD replication enabled).

One has to ask *why* you want to delete every single record from your DNS server. That's usually a really good way to break things really badly.